# XML into curly braces statement

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, configuration

Is there any mechanism to represent XML as curly braces statement . How  achieve this using C# ? 
For example, I have **such XML**:

```
<protocols>
  <bgp>
    <group>
      <name>23</name>
      <import>policy1</import>
    </group>
   </bgp>
</protocols>
```

Represented as **Cli configuration statement:**

```
protocols {
  bgp {
    group 23 {
      import policy1;
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: "As curly braces statement" is very vague. What *exactly* do you mean by "Cli configuration statement"? It looks *similar* to JSON, but not the same... my guess is that it's a vendor-specific format (Juniper?). I don't know of any direct tools... but what have you tried so far in converting this?

Comment: IThanks for reply! You are right! This is Junos. configuration( represents as XML and CLI statement).Initially, I had a configuration in Screenos(juniper).this predecessor of Junos. I parse this file, using regular expressions C# and assambly different classes (data). From this classes I create XML. Generally, for Junos itself is clear and itwould accept it.  But the system will also take another form( with curly braces), wich is more clear (readable) for peoples.

Comment: Is Junos itself capable of converting the XML version into the curly braces form? If so, I'd just let it do the work :)